# how to send a json string in a POST request to web server in Java?

Tags: json, http, post, request, apache-httpclient-4.x

So i need to send a json string in the request body for a POST request, all the searches on the web pointed me to really outdated examples with deprecated API.

I'd really appreciate if someone could point me to a more recent resource or better yet, provide an example themselves. I am using the Apache HttpClient btw. Also, i'm not sure how to set the content-type for the POST request.

P.S. If there is a way to do this without using the Apache HttpClient and instead use some native Java class, that'd be great too.

Comment: Ok, when you come back to this question. Scroll down a little and take a look at the links posted on the *right* side of the page (under the section ***Related***). I wager you will find your answer there as this question has been asked MANY times on Stackoverflow before.